# In a WebObjects app, is it possible to change the database connection settings without restarting the app?

Tags: webobjects

I have a WebObjects app that uses the Project Wonder framework. If I remember correctly, it seems like back in the day, before we started using Project Wonder, it was possible for us to change our DB connection settings without restarting the application. After moving to project Wonder a few years ago, we lost the ability to dynamically change the DB settings.  It appears that Project Wonder anticipates that the connection settings are already in place as a WebObjects property at the time of startup, so changing the properties after the app is up has no affect. We didn't fight it too much, at that time, and figured it wasn't a big  deal to just simply restart the app when the DB changes, since we didn't anticipate that such changes would come up frequently.

Things have change over the years, and requiring a restart after changing the DB is no longer as reasonable as it once was.  I've tried poking around to find what, in Project Wonder / WebObjects, is caching the settings, but haven't found the answer yet.  I was wondering if anyone has had any luck changing Database settings dynamically in a WebObjects / Project Wonder app.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is a "back in the day" or a "now using Project Wonder" issue. I think that the behavior changed when WO was ported to Java.

Theoretically, one should be able to do this. In practice, I do not think it will work well enough to be worth it. All of the data structures in WO and in EOF are lazily instantiated. If you want to switch databases, you need to destroy all, and I do mean ALL, of the objects that refer to the old database. Is it possible to find most of them and clear them? Yes, and it is not even too difficult. Is it possible to find all of the them? Maybe not.

For one thing, Java is a lot less dynamic than ObjC is. A lot of things are instantiated in static blocks in java. All of these class could have registered for the notifications that occur when an EOModel is changed. Did they all register for them? Probably not.

So, you can get rid of some of the application's state and you will be able to do some things with the new database and things may work for a while and then they may stop working. You might be able to figure out why. Or you could just re-start the darned app....

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just follow these lil instructions here ;)

To change the Connection at runtime you have to basically set the object store coordinator

You create a custom object store coordinator like this:

```java
NSMutableDictionary<String, String> temp = new NSMutableDictionary<String, String>();
temp.put("URL", String.format("%s?useBundledJdbcInfo=true", url));
temp.put("username", username);
temp.put("password", password);
temp.put("name", name);

connectionDictionary=temp.immutableClone();

// Create a new Object store coordinator
objectStoreCoordinator = new ERXObjectStoreCoordinator();
ERXModelGroup.setModelGroupForObjectStoreCoordinator(
    objectStoreCoordinator, ERXModelGroup.defaultGroup()
);

// Set the model that you want to use to connect to multiple databases
EOAdaptor adaptor =ERXDatabaseContext.registeredDatabaseContextForModel(
    ERXModelGroup.defaultGroup().modelNamed("YourModelName"), 
    objectStoreCoordinator
).adaptorContext().adaptor();

// update the connection dictionary
adaptor.setConnectionDictionary(
    updateDictionary(adaptor.connectionDictionary(), 
    connectionDictionary)
);
```

With this you can easily create a new editing context that points to the database of your choice

```java
ERXEC.newEditingContext(objectStoreCoordinator);
```

If your application is used by multiple users and they all need to switch between multiple DBs without interfeering with each other,  I recommend that you not use Shared Editing Context.

Like this you avoid people changing the object store coordinator to cause the others to point to that database too (not so funny).